# Find position of text in dynamic range google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range formula

```
ADDRESS( 302 ; ROW() ; 4 ; TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS( 401 ; ROW() ; 4 ; TRUE)
```

Starting at row 1 it would output `A302:A401`
i want then to find the position of a text in that range.

```
MATCH("*"&A1&"*";A302:A401;0)
```

I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to find the answer. By using `INDIRECT` around the address ranges it works. I only have to copy paste it in different fields and the range updates correctly.

```
=MATCH("*"&A1&"*";INDIRECT(ADDRESS(302 ; ROW()-2 ; 4 ; TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS( 401 ; ROW()-2 ; 4 ; TRUE));0)
```